# When adding a row in table, formula skips a row in addition. how to fix?

Tags: excel, dynamic, row, formula

My equation (located in cell J6) looks like this:

```
=IF(B6="POC",0,J5+I6)
```

When I add a row the cell that is pushed down (cell J6 becomes cells J7) skips a row in the formula where there is an addition for some reason. J5 should become J6 but doesn't in the formula.

```
=IF(B7="POC",0,J5+I7)
```

How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Can you provide more context? What cell was the first formula placed in? Which row was inserted?

Comment: If you're adding a row below `B6`, then `J5` won't change. I assume that's what you're doing?

Comment: Thanks guys. The first formula was placed on J6, i right clicked on that row and added row above. therefore original J6 was pushed to J7. J7 is the equation with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
=IF(B6="POC",0,INDEX(J:J,ROW(I6)-1)+I6)
```

This way, if you insert a row anywhere, the references are always reserved.

Note that `INDEX(J:J,ROW(I6)-1)` is effectively the same thing as just `J5`, but when a row is inserted, this changes to `INDEX(J:J,ROW(I7)-1)`, which effectively is the same as `J6`.

Comment: I can't add a + vote yet as I don't have 15 reputation. But this works magic. Thanks!

Comment: @B-CB. No problem. Thanks for accepting the answer.